# How to generate a dynamic model record based on another record

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a simple model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_member_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='',)
    team_member_phone_clean = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='',)
```

And a simple form:

```
class TeamAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
            model = Team
            fields = ( 'team_member_phone')
```

Users are able to input their phone in a `+44 123 123 123` format.

How do I strip any non-digit characters (e.g. whitespace and `+`) from `team_member_phone` and store the result in `team_member_phone_clean`?

Do I need to do this when the form is submitted, via `views.py` or can I write it as part of the model (which would be preferable), so it is generated dynamically (ie updates automatically)?

Note, I want to have both versions, such that I can represent the "user friendly" whitespace format when the number is edited again.

Comment: write a  new method in your form clean_team_member_phone() and remove whitespaces and '+'. When you do form.is_valid() it will do the work for you

Comment: @AjayGupta thanks; if I define a `def(mymethod)`, do i do that in `forms.py` and does it run automatically, or do I need to call it?

Comment: yes you have to define it in your form TeamAddForm and it will automatically be called when you check form.is_valid() provided you have override the form's clean method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that in the model's save:

```
import re

class Team(models.Model):
    team_member_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='',)
    team_member_phone_clean = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='',)

    def set_member_phone_clean(self):
        self.team_member_phone_clean = re.sub(r"(\s)|([^\d])", "", self.team_member_phone)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_member_phone_clean()
        super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks i) what should I define `clean_phone` as? ii) does the model save get updated every time the records are edited?

Comment: I added a sample method. You can play around with it to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to define it in your form TeamAddForm and it will automatically be called when you check form.is_valid() provided you have override the form's clean method

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TeamAddForm, self).clean()
    # do your processing here with self.fields['team_member_phone'] and return back the data
    return cleaned_data
```